# Accidentally deleted /etc/network/interfaces on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, etc

I have accidentally deleted 
`/etc/network/interfaces`

I have tried rebooting but the file still doesn't exist.

Creating file and rebooting now.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

**using DHCP**

Example1:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Example2:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Replace eth0 with your network interface card

restart networking services using the following command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

**static:**

```
# The loopback network interface
 auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
address xx.xx.xx.xx
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast xx.xx.xx.xy
network xx.xx.xx.xz
gateway yy.yy.yy.yy
dns-nameservers yy.yy.yy.yy
```

Example:

```
# The loopback network interface
 auto lo eth0
 iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.77
gatway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.254
network 192.168.0.0
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.254
```

Restart networking services :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: did auto lo
iface lo inet loopback. no effect.

Comment: what if i dont know most of those numbers

Comment: Use dhcp , i will edit my answer , what is you IP-router?

Comment: are you sure about "auto lo eth0"?

Comment: my adapter is apparently called p3p1. i did The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface p3p1 inet dhcp
after doing /etc/init.d/networking restart i did ping www.google.com and it says unknown host

Comment: Please edit and add the output of `uname -a` and `ifconfig` , you must replace `eth0` with your interface

Comment: added a picture

Comment: run `ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/2242619be110afa58a4296c26f892a8f.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44234/discussion-between-web-master-and-gad3r).

Comment: You can learn more about this file via `man interfaces`